# Magento adding .html in the middle of url after last category

Tags: magento2, overrides, url, htaccess

I migrated all my products and categories (thousands) over from M1 to M2 and persevered all the URL writes.
I have now found that if we modify a category in M2 it is adding a `.html` to the end of the category.

This ok as we used that format in the past on M1.
What I have noticed is that it is now adding `.html` into the middle of product URLs.

So what once would have been

```
/cat1/subcat1/testcat/producttitle.html
```

is now

```
/cat1/subcat1/testcat.html/producttitle.html
```

To avoid this I removed the suffix in the category and have now left it blank.
So the product URL would now look like

```
/cat1/subcat1/testcat/producttitle.html
```

As a result of this, I am now getting 404 errors on all category links from google as they
are looking for URL with `.html` extension.

The only solution I can see would be to also remove the `.html` for products as well, which
would result in all links from google failing to work.

The add a URL rewrite to the .htaccess file like this.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

so that it would redirect all pages with a `.html` extension to
the pages with no extension and regenerate URL rewrites for the products and categories.

Would this be the best solution to the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to solve this issue? I too am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/200164)